# Query for related projects in JIRA

Tags: jira

My organization uses JIRA as a tracking tool.
Of late i require to create a query to where in i need to search all issues reported in 'Project A' which have a link(link type: 'relates to') with a few of the issues reported in 'Project B' (By few issues i mean that i will have a query to filter out a sub set of issues from Project B).

issuetype = Story AND status = Open AND project = "Project A" AND relation type= 'relates to'  with ID in (select ID where issuetype = Story AND status = Open AND project = "ProjectB" )

I an mot being able to find a way how to link the two projects.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/148168/can-we-search-using-link-type-in-jira-5 for some suggestions